# Almacenar datos es una array o arreglo en C

Tags: array, c

Tengo un pequeño problema, debo crear un programa para leer una serie de números entre 0 y 9 y almacenarlos para luego operar con ellos, he pensado usar un array.

El problema me llega cuando debo pedir que el usuario que introduzca los números, no se almacenan.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que el programa acaba cuando el usuario introduzca 10.

El programa que tengo ahora es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10
int main(){
    int numero[N];
    int i=1, elegido;
    printf("Serie de numeros: (0-9): ");
    scanf("%d",&numero[0]);
    while(numero[i-1]!=10&&i<N){
        scanf("%d",&numero[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nEscriba la posicion que desea mirar: ");
    scanf("%d",&elegido);
    //mirar_izquierdo(int elegido, int numero[N]); Esta función está sin desarrollar
   // mirar_derecha(int elegido, int numero[N]);  Esta función está sin desarrollar

   return 0;
}
```

La cosa es que en el array no se guardan los valores introducidos, incluso se queda el programa parado y ni siquiera te deja meter otro.
He probado también con usar `for(i=1;numero[i-1]!=10&&i<N;i++)` en vez del while pero no funciono.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

el problema radica en que esta mal planteado tu código, sin embargo no te preocupes, eso es algo que nos ha pasado a todos; ahora tratare de darte una respuesta que despeje todas tus dudas.

Todo el problema comienza aquí:

```
printf("Serie de números: (0-9): ");
scanf("%d",&numero[0]);
    
while(numero[i-1]!=10&&i<N){
    scanf("%d",&numero[i]);
    i++;
}
```

la forma en que esta declarado el ciclo **while** es algo confusa para los humanos e incluso mas para la computadora, porque dice así:

```
**Mientras numero[en la posición i - 1] sea distinto de 10 
y i sea menor a N = 10, 
toma una entrada por teclado y almacenarla en numero[en la posición i], 
luego incrementa el valor de i**

Sin embargo hay un par de situaciones que complican esa logica:

La primera vez que se pide ingresar un numero es fuera del ciclo y se ingresa 
en la primera posición del array(0), luego dentro del ciclo se toma de nuevo la 
entrada del teclado y lo almacena en i - 1 = 0, lo cual reemplaza el valor que 
ya se había almacenado.

al poner && en el while, solo se ejecutara si se cumplen ambas condiciones lo 
cual hace mas complicado el funcionamiento correcto del ciclo.
```

Una mejor solución para tu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10


int main() {
    // variables del programa.
    int numero[N];
    int elegido;

    /**
     * Este ciclo recorre de 0 a N veces el arreglo[i] llenándolo con los valores ingresados
     * por el usuario, si el numero es igual a 10, retorna 0 y finaliza la ejecución
     * del programa. En caso contrario continua ingresando números hasta llegar al valor de N.
     * 
     * Si el numero ingresado es menor a 0 o mayor a 9, lo muestra como fuera de rango
     * y pide que ese numero sea ingresado de nuevo, no pasara de ahí, hasta ingresar
     * un numero valido.
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Digite una serie de números entre (0-9): ");
        scanf("%d", &numero[i]);


        if(numero[i] == 10) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (numero[i] < 0 || numero[i] > 9) {
            printf("Numero fuera de rango, digite de nuevo entre (0-9): ");
            scanf("%d", &numero[i]);

            // si el numero es = 10 finaliza el programa.
            if(numero[i] == 10) return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Escriba la posición que desea mirar entre (0-9): ");
    scanf("%d", &elegido);

    printf("El numero en la posición %d es %d\n", elegido, numero[elegido]);

    // finaliza exitosamente.
    return 0;
}
```

de esta forma quedaría mejor estructurado y mas legible tu código, usando un ciclo introducir el código aquí for y delegando algunas de las condiciones en sentencias if en otras lineas.

Espero que mi respuesta larga te sirva y despeje tus dudas. Agregue comentarios en el programa por si alguna parte no esta muy clara.

Te invito a que te sientes y analices el código un para de veces e incluso, trata de visualizar formas de mejorarlo. La mejor forma de mejorar programando es leyendo y escribiendo código.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda usar el &
Y si quieres pedir varios números no te recomiendo hacer scanf("%d",&numero[0]); ya que estas pidiendo un solo número, lo mejor (en tu caso) sería hacer un bucle for para pedir varios números

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo me falta en & en el primer scanf. Respecto a lo otro te referieres a usar ``` for(i=0;i<N&&numero[i-1]!=10;i++){scanf(%d, &numero[i];}``` ?

Comment: al principio para que los números 
se guarden correctamente.
```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
printf("Serie de numeros: (0-9): "); 
scanf("%d",&numero[i]);
}